# Monthly and annual arithmetic mean in valuations?

Tags: valuation, discounting, expected-return, compounding, mean

**I know this is back to basics but I am perplexed by it!!!**

Assume that the future value (FV) of an investment at the end of year 1 is 112, the annual arithmetic expected return is 12%, hence the present value (PV) today is 100 since 112/(1.12)=100.

It is also evident that the monthly arithmetic average expected return is 1% since 12%/12months= 1%.

Assume that a month has passed, what is the value of the investment? It is known that this is 120/(1.12)^(11/12)= 100.948879293.

However, we can also say that the 11 month expected (average) arithmetic return is 1% x 11 =11%. However, if we use this as the discount rate the result is different since 112/1.11= 100.900900901. Why is this approach wrong? At time 0 we use the 12% which is 1% x 12 but when we use this approach at the end of the first month/beginning of the second month, the result is inaccurate. The same holds for other months and the difference can be much larger than my example.

I have often seen (e.g., in value at risk calculations) that the annual expected return (in my example 12%) is divided by 12 and then multiplied by 3 to find the 3 month value at risk for instance. What is wrong with my approach in the valuation example?

I am confused about the fact that assuming that in ex ante valuations we use the arithmetic average return as the discount rate, if the arithmetic average return is 11% in my example, why is this not the correct discount rate? Or is it because the rate has to always be the 12% and what changes is the time (i.e., 1, 11/12, 11/11, etc) by definition? What is then the significance of the 1% monthly expected return and why is it used in some instances?

Answer (score 1):

Returns are usually quoted on annual basis but to arrive at right PV(or FV) you need to know the compounding term. Below are some examples.

1. 12% compounded annually: \$100 now is \$112 in 1 year. [100*(1+0.12)]
2. 12% compounded monthly: \$100 now is \$112.682 in 1 year. [100*(1 + 0.12/12)^12]
3. 12% compounded daily(365 days): \$100 now is \$112.747 in 1 year. [100*(1 + 0.12/365)^365]

Coming to numbers in your question.

1. "Assume that the future value (FV) of an investment at the end of year 1 is 112, the annual arithmetic expected return is 12%, hence the present value (PV) today is 100 since 112/(1.12)=100" -> this is 12% return compounded annually.
2. "I have often seen (e.g., in value at risk calculations) that the annual expected return (in my example 12%) is divided by 12 and then multiplied by 3 to find the 3 month value at risk for instance." - this probably would have been 12% compounded quarterly.

Finally I want to note that these differences in compounding may not be significant depending on the context you are using.